# How to change "niceness" while perfoming top command?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, top, process-priority, nice

I know that I can change the niceness using this command:

```
renice [-n] priority [[-p] pid ...] [[-g] pgrp ...] [[-u] user ...]
```

But it would be much more convenient if I could do it while scanning the processes in top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>r</kbd>. That's it! :-)

Reference: The 9th item in [12 TOP Command Examples in Linux](http://www.tecmint.com/12-top-command-examples-in-linux)

Answer (score 4):

**htop** gives you a user interface, that is easier to use. <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> are used to renice the high-lighted process. You need sudo permissions to decrease the nice value.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu
sudo apt update
sudo apt install htop

htop
```

Or if you want to decrease the nice value (can be dangerous)

```
sudo -H htop
```

Comment: I knew about htop. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I didn't know about htop! Thanks @sudodus! :-)

Comment: You are welcome, both of you :-)